# I'm utilizing an if/else statement to separate a data set into positive/negative values but have ran into an unused argument error

Tags: r, if-statement, append

I'm trying to separate a set of data with an if statement based on if a value is positive. I had it working and it generated correct data but it stopped and generated the unused argument error when I generated new data.
Here is the code I used.

```
In:
data_random1 = runif(100,1,100)
data_random2 = runif(100,1,100)
cd1 = data_grouped1
cd2 = data_grouped2
smth_ln = lowess(cd1,cd2)
dis = smth_ln$y - cd2
data_frame = data.frame(cd1,cd2,dis)
f = c()
y = c()
ifelse(data_frame$dis >= 0, f = c(f,data_frame$dis),y = c(y,data_frame$dis))
```

This generates the error:

```
Error in if (x > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

When I type this function seperate from the if statment it works so I am confused as to the issue.
I tried a workaround with:

```
for(x in c(dis[1:100])){if(x >= 0){f = c(f,x)}else{y=c(y,x)}}
```

but got the error:

```
Error in if (x > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What is `data_grouped1` and `data_grouped2`?

Comment: I bet whatever `data_frame$dis` is can't be coerced in to logical. What does `str(data_frame$dis)` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that the way you're introducing `f` and `y` in the `ifelse` function, is the way function arguments are introduced. You get the error, because the function is expecting a command for what to do when the statement is `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and instead you're giving it an argument that it's not expecting.

One way to work around that is to create a new variable in `dis` and take it from there. So it would look like:

```
data_frame$pos<- ifelse(data_frame$dis >= 0, 1, 0)
f<- data_frame$dis[which(data_frame$pos == 1)]
y<- data_frame$dis[which(data_frame$pos == 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data_random1 = runif(100,1,100)
data_random2 = runif(100,1,100)
cd1 = data_random1
cd2 = data_random2
smth_ln = lowess(cd1,cd2)
dis = smth_ln$y - cd2
data_frame = data.frame(cd1,cd2,dis)
f = c()
y = c()
for(i in 1:nrow(data_frame)){
  if(data_frame$dis[i] >= 0){
    f = c(f, data_frame$dis[i])
  } else{
    y = c(y, data_frame$dis[i])
  }
}
```